# Images are black in PDF

Tags: java, image, rendering, jfreechart, ireport

I'm creating piecharts using `JFreeChart`, use `chart.createBufferedImage(width,height)` and give the buffered image to IReport as an image parameter. In IReport I have an image and its image expression points to this parameter, so I can render the image. But when exported to PDF, images are covered with a black rectangle. Something about transparency or RGB, I guess.

There's a thread here about this problem and some suggested solutions, but I couldn't apply them to my problem, will you help me? Thanks.

The thread: http://www2.jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=21922&page=2#24710

Comment: Well, transparency or RGB are good guesses. *Are* the images you're trying to embed transparent? *Are* they RGB images?

Comment: well, I only got createBufferedImage() method, and I can't find a way to set RGB or trasparency values from JFreeChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Pekka, this is likely a limitation of [*Transparency in PDF files*](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/transparency).

> I can't find a way to set RGB or trasparency values from JFreeChart.

The [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) class includes a [`createBufferedImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#createBufferedImage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo%29) method that accepts an `imageType`, which is subsequently used to create the [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) . You may have to select the optimal one empirically.